# Huge non-paged pool increase in ram

Tags: windows-10, memory, memory-leaks

So I did some digging based on recommended tools found here.

When searching through RamMap, the Non-Paged pool is taking a ridiculous amount of RAM out of my 16 GBs as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQyfu.png). So I went to poolmon for help.

Poolmon showed that indeed, some drivers are taking huge amounts of RAM. I saw people recommending that you need to go to the 'details' tab, search for the 'product name' and update the driver. But most, if not all, of my problematic drivers own the product name `Windows OS` as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXmhy.png). I've already checked and my Windows is up to date.

Now I decided to do a check up after a restart, a week later and about 10 days later. Here are the results:

Immediatly after the restart, it all seemed well as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B3pc.png). No process manager picture but the non-paged pool was at about 400Mbs.

After a week, it increased drastically as shown in [process manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCJcN.png) and in [poolmon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R8wv.png)

After about 10 days, it almost doubled it self shown in [process manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF8Ef.png) and in [poolmon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuYgK.png)

Now I'm not really sure how to approach this. I would really like it if I didn't have to format any disc or reinstall Windows but it's completely unbearable so I would appreciate any form of help I can get.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Driver issues seem to be the most common. One post said a game was responsible for memory leaking.  Try using Task Manager, Memory usage by application.

Comment: I'm using the task manager. Without any application open, it's still peaking. After a restart, it all resets and then keeps on going up even if I don't play anything.

Comment: Try the PC Manufacturer's Driver Update app and update all drivers to see if that helps.

Comment: By PC Manufacturer you mean the manufacturer of the motherboard (PC is a custom built desktop)?

Comment: You need to look through all your hardware and get update Apps for each piece. I do not know any other way.

Comment: Sounds like a memory hole in a system driver. I would use Sysinternals Autoruns, select Drivers tab and hide all Microsoft entries. This is the list of drivers to check for updates. besides that you can try what Microsoft suggests: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/finding-a-memory-leak